# Wanna add Placeholder to input with the help of CSS3

Tags: css, placeholder

I know with the help of script it is possible. But due to some limitations can we do with the help of css3. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

yes. It is possible. You can use the following example.

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="email_field"/>
<label class="label">Email</label>
```

CSS code:

```
.email_field {
   width:95%;
   z-index:3;
   position:relative;
   background-color:transparent;
}
label {
   position:absolute;
   display:block;
   top:3px;
   left:4px;
   z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: what is your requirement?

Comment: can we add placeholder to a input box with css....like any fix would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use placeholder attribute on input

```
<input type="text" placeholder="placeholder_text"/>
```

Comment: buddy i asked it with CSS. i know with html5 we can do it

Comment: you didn't tell me you know html5, btw ...I don't think there is a way to do that in css3